# I have a graphic not lining up properly in IE 8 and IE 9 on a custom Wordpress Theme

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer-8, background, internet-explorer-9

I'm hoping someone can help me with a little glitch in IE8 and IE9 with a graphic background not lining up.

If you view this link in IE8 or IE9, you'll notice the "step" in the background. http://sager.hiringhook.com/

I'm working with a custom theme created specifically for this site.  Everything looks good in Chrome and Firefox, IE is just being a thorn in my side.

If anyone has a simple fix, please share..before I lose my hair.

Answer (score 0):

I looked for the *step* you mentioned but didn't see any difference in the site from Chrome to IE8.  The logo shifts down along with the featured photo in compatibility mode but nothing else seems to change across browsers.  Do you have a screenshot of what you see in IE?  I would love to replicate and help you solve the issue.